# How to erase StringBuilder memory with zero

Tags: c#, security, stringbuilder

I have a password stored in `StringBuilder` object. I am looking for a way to erase the password in memory. Does any of the following methods will achieve this:

1. Iterate through the StringBuilder characters and assign `'\0'`. Is
   this guaranteed to use the same memory if I have allocated
   sufficient memory initially?
2. Can I use any unmanaged API like `ZeroMemory()` or `SecureZeroMemory()`
   with `StringBuilder`? Any code samples?

EDIT:

Using `SecureString` is not an option for me since I am calling `CredUIPromptForCredentials()` to get the credentials.

Comment: i would use a securestring instead.

Comment: Try formatting so that code is marked as such, and that you have some line breaks (so you don't have a wall of text). Questions that are easier to read might get more responses.

Comment: Every StringBuilder.ToString() creates a new copy - so, no - it is not guaranteed to overwrite the used memory.

Comment: And you can't even pin buffer allocated by `StringBuilder` as far as I understand.

Comment: If you have the password in a `StringBuilder` you've already lost.  There is already a window for the password to be accessed, even if you make that window smaller.  The answer is not to shrink the window of time you're exposed, it's to not expose yourself in the first place.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simple answer is that none of the methods you are proposing are secure. And once you put a password into `StringBuilder`, it's game over. Don't use `StringBuilder` for storing a password, use `SecureString` instead, if you have to use a managed class.

Now, you say in comments that you are calling `CredUIPromptForCredentials`. So do that, but don't put the password into a `StringBuilder`. Put it into unmanaged memory, for instance allocated with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. Then when you are done with that unmanaged memory, do what the docs for [`CredUIPromptForCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177.aspx) say and call [`SecureZeroMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877.aspx) before you deallocate the unmanaged memory.

I note that the [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduipromptforcredentials) translation uses `StringBuilder` for the password parameter. Perhaps that is what has led you astray. You don't need to do that (you should not do that). Declare the parameter to have type `IntPtr` instead.

Comment: SecureString is a massive PITA to use though.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Well, that's how it goes with security. Security always involves trading convenience.

Comment: I call CredUIPromptForCredentials() to get the credentials passing a StringBuilder object and I think SecureString cannot be use here.

Comment: But nobody says you need to put it in a `StringBuilder`. Allocate unmanaged memory with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` for instance. Then when you are done with the unmanaged memory, do what the docs for `CredUIPromptForCredentials` say and call `SecureZeroMemory` on the unmanaged memory.

Comment: Using unmanaged memory seems to be the option. Any useful links?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - +1 upvote. very well nail hammering here buddy!! :)

Comment: You can use the "convenience" of SecureString and then allocate unmanaged memory for it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.securestringtoglobalallocunicode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, allocate unmanaged memory. Call your function. Call `SecureZeroMemory` when you are done.